# Bash stdout character limit

Tags: bash, file, limit, stdout

How can you limit the count of standard output characters that is redirected to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Command Substitution** to wrap the output pre-redirection, then use the offset **Parameter Expansion** to limit the number of characters like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=20

out=$(echo "this line has more than twenty characters in it")
echo ${out::limit} > /path/to/file
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ limit=20
$ out=$(echo "this line has more than twenty characters in it").
$ echo ${out::limit}
this line has more t
```

Comment: Cripes, I never cease to be amazed at how much I _don't_ know about bash.

Comment: @sarnold *Parameter Expansion* seems to be the biggest undervalued/unknown feature of not just `bash` but *any* POSIX compliant shell.  Time after time I see people calling `basename` or `dirname` which both can be done in native shell syntax using Parameter Expansion.  See [HERE](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) for a good link on usage as well as a **great** site on bash.

Answer (score 8):

Other ways (external)

```
echo $out| head -c 20
echo $out | awk '{print substr($0,1,20) }'
echo $out | ruby -e 'print $_[0,19]'
echo $out | sed -r 's/(^.{20})(.*)/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so *directly* into a file, but you can pipe through `sed` or `head`, etc. to pass on only part of the output.  Or as @SiegeX says, capture the output in the shell (but I would be wary of that if the output mis likely to be large).